# Comparing an Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, reflection

I've got an entity that I build, I take an instantiated entity and a modified entity.  This allows me to hold the initial data, to compare against the modified data.  The question, is what would be the ideal approach?  Should I implement `IEquatable` as an override on `Object.Equals` or implement `ICompare`?  My original implementation was:

```
var properties = typeof(TEntity).GetProperties();
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    var initialEntity = original.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(original, null);    
    var modifiedEntity = userChange.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(userChange, null);

    if(initialEntity.Equals(modifiedEntity) == false && !ignore.Contains(property.Name))
    {
        // Do Something
    }
}
```

My understanding was that it would return a `boolean`, also in this instance it would compare on *Value Equality*, I'm assuming though it is comparing based on reference equality.

Because it never distinguishes, it remains equal under all circumstances.

Comment: are sure is not the same instance?

Comment: Are those linq entities? if yes then the ObjectStateManager already holds all the changes you made to it

Comment: You might want to check some project I published some months ago: [TrackerDog](http://matiasfidemraizer.com/trackerdog). It does what you want to achieve already!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest answer:

- **If you need to test equality, implement `IEquatable<T>`** and override `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`
- **If you need to sort objects, implement `IComparable<T>`**

The default implementation of `Object.Equals()` determines if the memory location used by one object is the same as another object.  This is essentially what `Object.ReferenceEquals(obj1, obj2)` does, but dot net needs you to tell it how to determine if two objects you create are equivalent.

Additionally, the default implementation of `Object.GetHashCode()` is the 32 bit address (or portion of an address) of where the object is located in memory.  Unless you override it to generate a hash code that is a function of everything you compared in your `Equals()` method, you will get unexpected results when you attempt to store it in a hash set or use it as a dictionary key.

You may need to implement both, but it looks like in your case `IEquatable<T>` is the most pressing need.